# Arrange base R plot and ggplot togeter in R and save with high resolution

Tags: ggplot2

Dear members and seniors,

Hope you all are well. Does anyone know whether we could arrange base R plot and ggplot in R and could save high resolution (300 dpi) for publication. I tried to do it, but not work. So asking in case anyone knows and could share example.

Kind Regards,

synat

Comment: Perhaps the `patchwork` package could help on that. See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks you so much. I think it works with only ggplot, not base R plot because once I combined base R and ggplot. alway got error. Anyway, thank for your responses. Kind Regards, synat

Comment: OP... there is an example halfway down that linked page that literally shows the same ggplot and base R graphics plot next to each other.  See the section for "non-ggplot objects".  Ex: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp) + geom_point() + ~plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$disp, main = 'Plot 2')`